# Clearing a worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA I am writing some code that adds text to another worksheet from drop down boxes. I would like to add a button that 'resets' the workbook so that the worksheet that text is being added to is cleared and picking from the drop boxes can be started again.
I have come across the clear contents and clear formats code.

```
Cells.ClearContents

Cells.ClearFormats
```

However, I am unsure how to use these on the worksheet from a certain point as the bottom of the worksheet depends on how much text was added.

Comment: Fully qualify the range you want to clear.  The code you've put will clear all cells on the currently active worksheet.  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").ClearContents` will clear the contents from the specified range in the workbook that the code is in (ThisWorkbook).

Comment: How do I qualify the end of the range when it depends on the amount of text added each time?

Comment: If you're text is being added to the next row down - so, for example, text is in `B3:B7` you'd fix the start cell and look from the bottom of the sheet up to last cell containing text - same as going to the last row and pressing `Ctrl+Up`.  In code this would be: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"): Debug.Print .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Address: End With`.   [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

Comment: Broken down a little - `Cells(3, 2)` is cell `B3` and `Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End (xlUp)` is the last cell containing data in column B.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it worked. Is there anyway of using VBA to remove data validation drop down boxes?

Comment: IIRC' `myRange.Validation.Delete` where `myRange` is the range where you want the data validation removed. Pease note, we are not a human powered search engine and [the answer to this question can be answered with a simple search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Is+there+anyway+of+using+VBA+to+remove+data+validation+drop+down+boxes&t=hs&va=l&ia=web)